# cygwin make: execvp: g++: Bad file number

Tags: makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to compile `glui` sources in cygwin. When I'm running `make` I get the following output

```
g++ -I./ -I./include -I/usr/X11R6/include -c glui_add_controls.cpp
make: execvp: g++: Bad file number
make: *** [glui_add_controls.o] Error 127
```

But it works perfectly if I just compile this file with

```
g++ -I./ -I./include -I/usr/X11R6/include -c glui_add_controls.cpp
```

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

Run Cygwin's setup.exe and search for "make". Install.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually had already `make` installed, but after reinstalling it everything seems to work. However, I'm not sure whether this was the solution or if something else has changed since I posted the question. I am marking the answer as accepted.